# Validation method error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following method to ensure that an entered username does not already exist.

```
protected void checkUsername(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    string connString = "Data Source=server;Initial Catalog=database;User Id=username;Password=password;";
    string cmdText = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM igs_users WHERE username = @username";

    using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdText, conn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
            Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();

            args.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get the following error.

System.ArgumentException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147024809
  Message=No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox to a known managed provider native type.
  Source=System.Data

The debugger gives me this error for the below line.

```
Int32 count = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```

Any idea what's wrong with this code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would think it's the line

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
```

Is `username` a TextBox? If so, you should change the line to:

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
```

The line as it currently stands attempts to bind the TextBox control itself to the `@username` parameter. The correction binds the text within the TextBox control to `@username`.

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.  Jeez, such a simple fix too.

Comment: I wish I could say I've never done anything like that, but I have. :-)